# Access Generator Result in Finally Block

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, generator, finally

Is there a way to access the final value of the iterator in a finally block in a generator?

```js
function*generator() {
 try {
  let value1 = yield(1)
  let value2 = yield(2)
 } finally {
  console.log("Ending, how to access the result? (4)")
} }

var iterator = generator()
var result1 = iterator.next(1)
var result2 = iterator.return(4)
```

Comment: Can't you just declare the values outside of the `try`?

Comment: No, the value is determined outside by iterator.return(value)

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not possible to access the argument passed to `.return()` inside the generator. It's the same as a `return` statement inside the `try` block - you can only overwrite the return value in the `finally` clause, but not read it.